# How do i persist my textview text when navigating to that screen

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, textview

Hi i have some query of how can i use sharedPreference to persist my tetview text. am implementing game in that i have to develop score table using textviews. am able to sort the textview text but the thing is when ever i navigate to that screen every time its got cleared and need to enter new string.. let me know how can i view already entered scores in that textview.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hi every one any update on this thing..please let me know..

Answer (score 0):

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: the code which i given above keeps the data until an application ends. Are you using SharedPreferences.Editor to update the old value with new value

Answer (score 0):

onPause you can do the following:

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(STATE_VARIABLE_FILE, 0);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

editor.putString("score", edit_text.getText().toString().trim());

editor.commit();

OnResume place something like below:

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(STATE_VARIABLE_FILE, 0);
edit_text.setText(settings.getString("score", ""));

Comment: Hey tyler where i need to call this onpause and onresume methods??

Comment: In the activity that you want to use the information. You can Override the default onPause and onResume methods. Probably just like you are doing for onCreate

Answer (score -1):

use `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outState)` to restore `TextView` Value.